# ActionScript: Using 'in' on protected/private variables?

Tags: actionscript

Is there any way to mimic the `in` operator, but testing for the existence of `protected` or `private` fields?

For example, this:

```
<mx:Script><![CDATA[
    public var pub:Boolean = true;
    protected var prot:Boolean = true;
    private var priv:Boolean = true;
]]></mx:Script>

<mx:creationComplete><![CDATA[
    for each (var prop in ["pub", "prot", "priv", "bad"])
        trace(prop + ":", prop in this);
]]></mx:creationComplete>
```

Will trace:

```
pub: true
prot: false
priv: false
bad: false
```

When I want to see:

```
pub: true
prot: true
priv: true
bad: false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just try to access it and catch resulting errors. :)

`in` is unaware of any namespaces currently opened (including private and protected in your case), and will only look within the public namespace.

`in` for objects actually just calls `Object::hasOwnProperty`. Unfortunately, you effectively cannot override this method to alter its behaviour. the **only** class that can influence it is `flash.utils::Proxy`, which actually uses `flash_proxy::hasProperty` to to determine the return value of `hasOwnproperty`.
So no, other than trying, there's no other way sadly.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
  <mx:creationComplete>
    for each (var prop:String in ["pub", "prot", "priv", "bad"])
    {
      try
      {
        t.text += prop + ":" + this[prop] + "\n";
      }
      catch (e:Error)
      {
        t.text += prop + ": false" + "\n";
      }
    }
  </mx:creationComplete>
```

Comment: since you have the required connections, could you maybe kindly ask to change this behaviour? :) because this is really quite sad.

Comment: Yea, this is what I'm doing now: `function hasProp(name) { try { this[name]; return true; } catch (e:ReferenceError) { /* do nothing */ }; return false; }`… But it's pretty lame :(